# Постоянный запуск билда на дженкинсе

Tags: git, bitbucket, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

У меня есть jenkins и проект на битбакете. Я настроил запуск билда по коммиту в битбакет. Если билд прошел успешно, я хочу запушить мои изменения, полученные при работе билда, в ветку, при коммите которой, запускается эта джоба. Я не хочу повторно запускать билд, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Коммит -- это локальная фиксация изменений. Пуш -- это фиксация изменений в ремоуте. Билды запускаются по изменениям в ремоуте, т.е. изменения уже запушены. Не очень понятно, что вы еще хотите получить?

Comment: При пуше в ветку А тригерится джоба на дженкинсе. Дженкинс, если джоба успешна, делает изменения, коммитит их и пушит в ветку А. после чего джоба запускается снова. Хочется, чтобы после пуша дженкинса джоба не тригерилась

Comment: *"если джоба успешна, делает изменения, коммитит их и пушит в ветку А"* -- вы используете gated check-in?

Comment: нет, что это такое и как его использовать?

Comment: Если нет, то эта часть вам не нужна: *"если джоба успешна, делает изменения, коммитит их и пушит в ветку А"*. Когда билд запускается, изменения **уже** находятся в ветке А и не нужно ничего снова в нее пушить.

Comment: Нет, нужно, так как изменения делает дженкинс, дженкинс меняет код, он что-то удаляет, что-то добавляет и это что-то нужно закомитить

Comment: @andreycha похоже, что на каждый коммит разработчика Jenkins делает ещё один коммит.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, при такой задаче правильней всего использовать две ветки/два репозитория с различными джобами

Comment: Иван, у меня под рукой нет дженкинса и я не смог наделать скриншотов. Я вам буду очень благодарен, если вы сделаете пару штук и добавите в мой ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заведите метку, обозначающую, что для данной задачи не нужен запуск CI, например `[skip ci]`. Когда Jenkins делает коммит, пускай добавляет эту метку в текст сообщения коммита.

При запуске конвейера (pipeline) в первую очередь проверяйте наличие метки в сообщении последнего коммита текущей ветки. Есть расширение [Jenkins CI Skip](https://wiki.jenkins.io/x/7gBCB), но оно давно не обновлялось.

Если оно не работает, можно сделать ту же проверку вручную. Сначала определите наличие метки в сообщении коммита и экспортируйте переменную в окружение.

```
if [[ $(git show -s --format=%B) == *"skip ci"* ]]; then
    export SKIPCI=1
fi
```

После добавьте условие: если метки нет, выполнять остальную часть конвейера.

Answer (score 1):

Проще создать юзера jenkins в bitbucket и сконфигурить git-config на jenkins'е.
После чего исключить username jenkins из коммитеров которые триггерят hook.
[image: screen]